# Need suggestion on temporary data storage of CSV data for validation purposes

Tags: java, csv, oracle11g, spring-batch, temp-tables

We have a requirement wherein user can upload bulk amount of data through CSV file, this may contain 20-30k records. Now we need to validate each record before inserting it into oracle DB. We also have a mongoDB used for some other business logics.

The approach we are going with is - save the records in mongodb(temporary), validate the records, dump all valid records into oracle.  We are using spring-batch for CSV uploads.

is this a recommended approach or is there any alternative approach you use ? Also can we use oracle temporary tables for CSV bulk upload.

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating an *external table*? It is just a "pointer" to the CSV file so you don't actually load anything into the database. Good point is that you can write (PL/)SQL against it, perform validation and insert only valid data into the target table. That saves you from loading data twice (Mongo first, Oracle next) as you do everything within Oracle.

Comment: I have been digging into external tables. Thank you pointing it out!. Do we need to create a SP which will have script for  creating external table and loading of CSV.
Call this SP from java code passing in the file name, after loading, read data in batches, validate it and insert valid data  into table ?

Comment: Create external table once, use it many times. Don't create it *dynamically* (i.e. in a stored procedure, as you've said). You'll see an option to *preserve* or *delete* rows on commit - pick the one you find the most appropriate. Difference is "when" its data will be removed (at the end of session or transaction). The rest of your comment is OK - you'd do everything else from the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

We have also used spring-batch for this kind of use case something similar to mentioned in this link;
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-batch-csv-processing

However, I don't see a point in using an additional MongoDB just to temporarily store the records.
If you really need to have an intermediary layer, then I would suggest you to use some kind of cache like REDIS.
Maintenance of REDIS is much simple and easier compared to MongoDB

Comment: MongoDB was already in place for some other business logic, so we thought of using it also for temporary storage to validate the CSV records. Back to your answer, will it be feasible to use REDIS for validation of that many CSV records, I was planning to use a temporary table in oracle itself which would resemble the original table